# Implementing Row Level Security in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, row-level-security

Is there a built-in feature, or way to simulate RLS(Row Level Security) in SQL Server 2008 as found in Oracle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This MS whitepaper outlines how to do it.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966395.aspx

You take the permissions away from the table, then create a series of security tables and roles that allow you to validate each level for the user.  After you setup your security checking on the user, you use a view to filter what the user can query via the security levels and the user's login.  Then you have insert, update, delete instead of triggers on the view to redirect the action to the table.