# MySQL: How do I lock individual rows in a table?

Tags: mysql

To increase the security of the app I'm working on, I want to be able to protect against any sort of db modification. I know I can lock entire tables from mysql users, but what about individual rows?

Would I still be able to add new rows to the table? maybe for just one particular table, only the SELECT and INSERT commands are allowed?

Comment: but then if the records that the views get the data from changes, the data within the views changes as well.

Comment: The title of the post relates to "locking" rows yet the details ask about access control. Understand that the term "lock" in database parlance relates to concurrent access to the data, e.g. a "shared lock" permits other connections to read but not modify the data, versus an "exclusive lock" which blocks other connections from doing anything (isolation level aside). This isn't the same concept as the types of actions one can perform on the data, e.g. select, update, insert, delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to permit inserting new rows and querying existing rows, but you do not want to permit updating or deleting rows. If that is correct, then you'll want to create a MySQL user that has only INSERT and SELECT privileges on the table(s) in question. Do not grant UPDATE and DELETE privileges.

To [grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) INSERT and SELECT privileges to user foo on my_table:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON my_table TO 'foo'@'localhost';
```

To [revoke](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/revoke.html) UPDATE and DELETE privileges from user foo on my_table:

```
REVOKE UPDATE, DELETE ON my_table FROM 'foo'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be "Row level security". MySQL doesn't have it, so you'd need to implement yourself.

For example, an "AddedBy" column can be used to restrict data changes to other members in the same group. Of course, if the Addedby user changes group you have to track this

To restrict allow INSERT and SELECT only, just GRANT these permissions.

Otherwise, please add more use cases

Comment: That's wrong: ["MySQL uses row-level locking for InnoDB tables, and table-level locking for MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE tables."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-locking.html)

Comment: @feeela: I said "Row level security". I did not say "Row level locking". Read my answer: don't comment on what I didn't write. To help you read these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7942301/27535 and http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/restricting_access.htm

Comment: I gave this response a +1 because the title of the post asks about individual rows and the description mentions security. Perfectly reasonable response, IMHO. It doesn't deserve the -1 that someone gave it.

Comment: Gotta love the downvotes from people who don't read the answer properly. +1 from me for proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a specific database users for your application with limited rights (No INSERT, DELETE) for the desired tables.